# Running script based on Category

Tags: functions, categories, child-theme

I have a child theme with function.php where I am running a script in the header but now I want to tweak it to run only on posts listed under one category and avoid on homepage or other categories. Here is my existing code which I modified but it is firing the script on the entire website.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'mailchimp_wp_head');
function mailchimp_wp_head() {
    ?>
        <?php if ( is_category( 93 ) ) :?> 
        <script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/hidden.js");</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks good, so are you sure the *category ID* is `93`? There could also be plugin or other code which is adding the script on your site, so try deactivating plugins.

Comment: Adding code if ( is_category( 93 ) did have any effect. It is being fired on the entire site like before adding.

Comment: I don't understand, but you mean, "did have" or "did *not* have"? And as I said, your code should work.

Comment: This is my current live code 

add_action('wp_head', 'mailchimp_wp_head');
function mailchimp_wp_head() {
    ?>
        
        <script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/hidden.js");</script>
        
    <?php
}

I tried modifying it as in the question but it still fires on every category

Comment: Then it sounds like a caching issue. Try clearing your site and browser caches.

Comment: @SallyCJ The one added in the question as mentioned earlier is still firing on all categories and is not limited to ID 93

Yes I do clear cache after every edit

Comment: In that case, try `var_dump( is_category( 93 ) );` at the top in the function, then visit the homepage, a single post and a category other than with the ID `93`. What are the dump output?

Comment: @SallyCJ it just print "var_dump( is_category( 93 ) );" on top of screen. Please note I am not a PHP coder

Comment: I mean, `function mailchimp_wp_head() { var_dump( is_category( 93 ) );` - add it like that... But if you still see the text as-is, then post your functions file, who knows if it's missing the `<?php` tag.

Comment: @SallyCJ it gives bool(false) on the top on every category post. I tried few posts in each category

Comment: Wait, did you mean, you want to add the JS only on *single* posts pages (e.g. `example.com/hello-world`) in the category 93? Edit: Lol, sorry. Can we just delete our comments? I think I got it now. Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> run only on **posts** listed under one category

I highlighted that "posts" because if so, then the [conditional tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) you should use is [`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) and not [`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) which is for *category archive pages* (e.g. `example.com/category/foo`) — so for example, `is_category( 93 )` checks if the current archive page is for the category (with the ID of) 93, whereas `in_category( 93 )` checks if the current post is in the category 93.

So try with:

```php
<?php if ( is_single() && in_category( 93 ) ) :?> 
<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/hidden.js");</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is still running the script in every category posts

Comment: I will try to explain in layman's language. There are two categories CAT-A (ID 92) and CAT-B (ID 93). Each Category has 5 posts. I want to restrict firing script CAT-B (ID 93) but it is firing on both categories and homepage even after using your new code mentioned above using is_single and in_category

Comment: Then looks like you just need some PHP condition there.. try `is_single() && ( in_category( 93 ) && ! in_category( 92 ) )`

Comment: So did that work? If so and if my answer answered your question, please consider marking my answer as "correct" - just tick the check-mark next to my answer.

Comment: Yes, the original code-shared by you with is_single && in_category works. There was a mistake on my part initially as the same code was in widget so it was firing. Thanks for your help.